# jQuery.click срабатывает сам при загрузке

Tags: jquery, click

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема. При загрузке страницы автоматически сам по каким-то причинам срабатывает click. Причем, даже если меняю цель на любой другой объект, например P, все равно при загрузке самовольно выполняется клик.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".button").click(alert("hello")) 
});
```

Заранее спасибо Товарищи!

Comment: У вас ваш код обернут в функцию $(document).ready(...). Эта функция автоматически запускается после того, как DOM полностью загрузился. Для того, чтобы у вас не срабатывал клик, вынесите его за пределы этой функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сам клик и вызываете вот так:

```
$(".button").click()
```

Если нужно повесить обработчик, то надо писать:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```